# .Net Https Client Certificate Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, ssl, iis-7

I'm fairly new to HTTPS/SSL/TLS and I'm a bit confused over what exactly the clients are supposed to present when authenticating with certificates.

I have performed following process and it works well in SOAP UI

1. I have generated .jks file using java keystore command. Using this .jks file
   I have generated a .crt file.
2. I have shared .crt file generated above with the server team for whitelisting it.
3. I have a JSON request that I need to pass to the server and get JSON response back.
4. Set Authorization to basic and pass it in the header of every request.
5. Set ClientID and ClientSecretKey in the header for every request.
6. All the above process works well in SOAP UI.
7. Following is the json request I am passing
   { 
   "requestMsg":"B6FFF4C33AFBAA30D51DE049CB3CA4357E32C632DFBC7D7CA0461920F765980A6632943AD811B7E20205696C6A26105E24F7A2FC85979CDE1352BD35DEA620C594CC8A4B58FF408FD8967F69D6F970C186028ED5BD6A089B9F13924D2F9B44811027DA9039EA7136D4EA57D73584A0FFE2BCB990A25AE701EFF5042F3C709992C0C57BCEE0B8B651918ACE684BCE645D6A4A222A90EAA06A3A8D175A5A0E58EBACB8E1BBCBE98814D03B416FBC241C01E3CCA530E7ED1033AA639BA81A7B458562FFAF1B1D80DE098466DD0BBF95E50550501614BC9706C3943705BDF37108376CCD6FD46A00CECC1D4166A0CFCA02B7",
   "agentInstitutionId":"YS01"
   }

8) When I am trying to do same using my .net web application, the below are the issues which I am facing

- How to Pass .crt certificate along with HTTP web request.
- Settings for configuring it in IIS.
- Is there any URL or steps that need to be done for attaching .crt file with 
  each request. ( please give pointwise steps)

Comment: Quite old, but maybe helpful for you: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/901183/how-to-call-a-web-service-by-using-a-client-certificate-for-authentica

Comment: I have tried to use to same steps as mentioned above.But i always get error as 401 unauthorized. Its works well with SOAP UI.

In SOAP UI.
I have added SSL keystore as jks file.Is there any  way by which we can add .jks file to asp.net application directly